# Efficient way to check if string contains value of vector<string>?

Tags: c++, string

I'm pretty new to C++ programming but for certain reasons I need to develop a small tool in C++. I've written the same tool in C# already. Right now I'm trying to check if my string contains a value that is stored in a std::vector. In C# this is pretty straight forward, simply using something like this:

```
if(string.Contains(myarray)) { // do sth. }
```

In C++ this seems way harder to achieve. I googled quite a bit but so far I found only solutions to check if the WHOLE string exists in an array and not just a certain part of it.

Comment: Are you checking to see if one of the elements in the vector is the same as the string or if one of the elements in the vector in contained within the string?

Comment: The second thing you mentioned. I'm trying to find out if on of the elements in the vector is contained within the string.

Comment: Looking at the documentation of [`System.String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx), I see a method named Contains that takes a String, and two that take single Chars. Where is this method that takes a whole array?

Comment: I suspect that you're using a custom `String` extension method, as it doesn't appear to be in dotnet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `std::string` does not have a method that can see if a element of a vector is in a string like C# does.  What it does have though is [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) which can determine if a string is contained within the string you call `find` on.  You could use that like

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
// fill words
std::string search_me = "some text";
for (const auto & e : words)
{
    if (search_me.find(e) != std::string::npos)
    {
        // e is contained in search me.  do something here
        // call break here if you only want to check for one existence
    }
}
```

This is O(N*complexity_of_find).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for and it's working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop and the `find` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [std::find_first_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_first_of/)

Not sure if I understood your exact problem, though. Could you give a small example of what your are trying to find in what?

Answer (score 0):

If you need more effective way to find several substrings in string than straightforward find string-by-string, you can use [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm)
It uses [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to hold substrings. [First google link to c++ implementation](https://github.com/blockchaindev/aho_corasick)